# Is a fiber product of flat morphisms flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose we have morphisms of schemes $f : X\rightarrow S$ and $g : Y\rightarrow S$, and a morphism $Z\rightarrow X\times_S Y$ such that the induced morphisms $Z\rightarrow X, Z\rightarrow Y$ are flat.

Are there mild assumptions on $f,g$ (eg, separated, finiteness,...etc) such that $Z\rightarrow X\times_S Y$ is flat?

Comment: Even with $X=Y=Spec(l)$, $S=Spec(k)$, with $k,l$ fields, $X\times_S Y$ can be singular, so you can get infinite projective dimension at some points of $Z$.

Comment: Have you checked a diagonal morphism? The $f,g$ seem about as nice as possible there.

Comment: @A.G. That would give a nice answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Hanno Ok, I will try to merge it with Hoot comment in a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An elementary example is the one given above by Hoot, $f=g:\mathbb A_k^1 \to k$ and $Z \to X\times_SY$ the diagonal of $f$ ($f$and $g$ are as nice as possible). You obtain a morphism of projective dimension 1 and then it's not flat.

But you can also obtain that $Z \to X\times_SY$ is of infinite projective dimension in many cases: let $l|k$ be an inseparable field extension (finite if you want) $X=Y=Spec(l)$, $S=Spec(k)$. Then $X\times_SY= Spec(l)\times_kSpec(l)$ is singular, so you can get infinite projective dimension at some points of $Z$ (for instance, taking again the diagonal as Hoot suggested , $Spec(l) \to Spec(l)\times_kSpec(l)$, or more generally the diagonal of any non smooth morphism $X=Y \to S$ of finite type).

Comment: I wasn't even thinking of something this fancy! It seems like the diagonal embedding of $\mathbf A^1_k \to k$ is already a problem.

Comment: @Hoot I'm sorry for the misunderstanding of your comment. I was thinking in how far from flat can be (infinite projective dimension) and I though that your answer was in the same direction. Now I see that your answer is more natural and elementary. I have edited the answer including your example in its easier form.